# Database schema pattern for grouping records

Tags: sql, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

I'm looking for a design pattern to manage records in a relational database which belong together, e.g. grouping multiple contacts. The group itself does not need to be an entity. A group should have an unlimited count of members.

It should be possible to run a query to get other group members of a given record.

My idea is to manage it in one table:

```
GROUPINGS
  integer group
  integer member_id

primary_key (group, member_id)
foreign_key (member_id)
```

**EDIT:** Beware that `group` is **not** a foreign key. It's just a unique identifier. It should be increased for every member group which is built.

Here is an example content:

```
GROUPINGS group | member_id
          -----------------
              1 | 10
              1 | 11
              1 | 12
              2 | 20
              2 | 21
              3 | 10
              3 | 40
```

This example contains three groups: (10,11,12) and (20,21) and (10,40). You see that 10 is included in two groups.

To query the "neighbors" of member 10 we can use this SQL statement:

```
SELECT g2.member_id
FROM groupings g1
JOIN groupings g2 ON g1.group      = g2.group 
                 AND g1.member_id != g2.member_id
WHERE g1.member_id = 10

=> 11,12,40
```

What do you think? Perhaps this is a known pattern - are there links to find more about this?

**EDIT:** Renamed table "groups" to "groupings" and renamed attribute "group_id" to "group" to make it obvious that a record in this table is not a group - it's a link between a group and a member. Group is not an entity.

Comment: Can a member belong to more than 1 group?

Comment: @Chris: Yes, this is possible. I have enhanced the example to demonstrate it.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Comment: There is no group entity in my schema - and it should not be required. Your schema is a solution for a different problem.

Answer (score 1):

What you have outlined is a pretty standard solution, a relational table between two entities - Group and Member.  I am sure there are alternatives, but this is the solution I would go with.

Comment: My answer assumes that you also have a group and a member table.

Comment: Because group_id is not a foreign key this is some kind of of special solution. There is no group table. I will rename the table in the original post to avoid this misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

Looks fine to me - is a normal solution to end at if a member can be part of multiple groups, which presumably they can.

The only suggestion I'd make is with your SQL query - I'd use a JOIN instead, but that's nothing to do with your schema:

```
SELECT g2.member_id
FROM groups g1
    INNER JOIN groups g2 ON g1.group_id = g2.group_id AND g1.member_id <> g2.member_id
WHERE g1.member_id = 10
```

Comment: You are right, a JOIN is nicer to read, but it's just syntactic sugar for most db's. I have edited my post above. And yes, a member can be part of multiple groups.